# Convert to numbers in Android app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an Android app and I have gotten stuck. I am getting input text with EditText and I need to convert it to a number (as I need to do some mathematical functions). My problem is that none of the integer.something functions works with EditText. Could you suggest something?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Parsing numbers is pretty easy in Java:

```
TextView numberView = (TextView)findViewById( ... );
double doubleNumber = Double.parseDouble( numberView.getText().toString() );
float floatNumber = Float.parseFloat( numberView.getText().toString() );
int intNumber = Integer.parseInt( numberView.getText().toString() );
```

You get the idea.  If you want floating point numbers (decimals) then double or float depending on the precision you need.  For integer numbers int works.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to get the `String` value from the `EditText`:

```
String stringValue = EditText.getText().toString();
```

and then you can convert it into an `int`:

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(stringValue);
```

and now `value` will hold the int value of the text in the `EditText`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the text from the EditText as a string first:

```
double d = Double.valueOf(myEditText.getText().toString());
```

Or

```
int i = Integer.valueOf(myEditText.getText().toString());
```